# VB6 XmlHttp.send STRING is not working. Fixed using Cstr(String). Help to understand

Tags: vb6, xmlhttprequest

I am using Visual Basic 6 for an old video game and I am implementing an API written in Node.js. (http://www.argentumonline.org)

Anyway this is my function

```
Public Sub ApiEndpointSendResetPasswordAccountEmail(ByVal Email As String, ByVal NewPassword As String)
    'Este endpoint envia un email para cambiar password al usuario

    UrlServer = GetVar(IniPath & "Server.ini", "CONEXIONAPI", "UrlServer") & "/api/v1/emails/resetAccountPassword"

    Dim Parameters As String
    Parameters = "newPassword=" & NewPassword & "&emailTo=" & Email

    Call SendPOSTRequest(UrlServer, Parameters)
End Sub


Private Sub SendPOSTRequest(ByVal Endpoint As String, ByVal Parameters As String)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set XmlHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")

    XmlHttp.Open "POST", Endpoint, False
    XmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    'Por alguna razon tengo que castearlo a string, sino no funciona, la verdad no tengo idea por que ya que la variable es String
    XmlHttp.send CStr(Parameters)

ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Call LogError("Error POST endpoint: " & Endpoint & ". La Api parece estar offline. " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.description)
    End If
End Sub
```

The code works fine, but in this line:
`XmlHttp.send CStr(Parameters)` If I do not cast the `Parameters` to string the app will not work and `XmlHttp` has an error that said something like `The Resource can not be found`. Parameters is already a string.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you pass Parameters `ByVal`? Does the behavior change if you omit that?

Comment: I know you can pass parameters to a function ByVal and ByRef and that is it , or am I missing something?

Comment: Does it change the behavior if you omit it? `ByVal` with strings acts differently than `ByVal` with numerics. It's almost never needed with strings, which is why I asked.

Comment: I just tried removing the ByVal and not putting anything, and it happens the same/.

Whats the default behaviour of vb when you don't specify if is ByVal or ByRef

Comment: VB6 defaults to `ByRef`, which as I said acts differently with strings. It shouldn't make any difference in this case but it was the only thing that struck me as out of the ordinary. If the code you show is exactly what you run (cut and pasted from your code) then I see no explanation for that behavior. What type does `XmlHttp.send` expect -- a Variant or a String? You could also try `XmlHttp.send (Parameters)` to see if a forced evaluation changes the behavior. But regardless, it looks as if it should work as you expect.

Comment: This is a bug w/ `XMLHTTP` -- it's `Send` method cannot handle `VT_BYREF` variants. You can use `CVar` for a generic fix -- this "strips" `VT_BYREF` both from strings and byte-arrays. There is no equivalent to `CStr` for byte-arrays in VB6 but *any* expression will effectively strip `VT_BYREF` e.g. `Parameters & ""` or `(Parameters)` the latter being a bit misleading as the parens are *not* part of function call but a redundant expression on the first parameter.